# Why there is no log output in Scala + Akka Typed App?

Tags: java, scala, akka, slf4j, typed

I have an issue that I don't have any log output in my program. Please, help me solve the problem and tell me where I did mistake.
The app is meant to be a Chat app. It consists UserActor, Main, RoomActor.

**Main**:

```
package Chat

import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Behavior}
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

object Main extends App {
    sealed trait MainActor

    def apply(): Behavior[MainActor] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
        val system: ActorSystem[Nothing] = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "ChatSystem")

        val userActor = system.systemActorOf(UserActor(), "userActor")

        val roomActor = system.systemActorOf(RoomActor(), "roomActor")

        userActor ! UserActor.CreateUser("John", "Doe", 25, system.deadLetters)
        val roomName = "General"
        roomActor ! RoomActor.CreateRoom(userActor, roomName)

        userActor ! UserActor.SendMessageToRoom(roomActor, "Hello, everyone!", "John")

        Thread.sleep(5000)
        system.terminate()

        Behaviors.receiveMessage {
            case _ =>
                context.log.info("Unknown message for MainActor")
                Behaviors.same
        }
    }
}
```

**UserActor**:

```
package Chat

import Chat.RoomActor.RoomCommand
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, Behavior}
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

import java.util.UUID

object UserActor {
    sealed trait UserCommand
    case class CreateUser(name: String, surname: String, age: Int, userActor: ActorRef[UserCommand]) extends UserCommand
    case class User(name: String, surname: String, age: Int, userId: String, userActor: ActorRef[UserCommand])
    case class SendMessageToRoom(room: ActorRef[RoomCommand], content: String, userName: String) extends UserCommand
    case class LeftRoomNotification(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], roomName: String) extends UserCommand
    case class JoinRoomNotification(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], roomName: String) extends UserCommand
    case class ReceiveMessage(sender: ActorRef[UserCommand], content: String) extends UserCommand

    def apply(): Behavior[UserCommand] = userBehavior(Map.empty)

    private def userBehavior(users: Map[String, User]): Behavior[UserCommand] =
        Behaviors.receive{(context, message) =>
            message match {
                case ReceiveMessage(sender, content) =>
                    context.log.info(s"User ${context.self} received message from $sender: $content")
                    Behaviors.same
                case SendMessageToRoom(room, content, userName) =>
                    users.get(userName) match {
                        case Some(user) =>
                            room ! RoomActor.BroadcastMessage(user.userActor, content)
                        case None =>
                            throw new Exception(s"Unknown User $userName!")
                    }
                    Behaviors.same
                case CreateUser(name, surname, age, userActor) =>
                    val userId = UUID.randomUUID().toString
                    val newUser = User(name, surname, age, userId, userActor)
                    context.log.info(s"User $newUser added in user list")
                    context.log.info(s"Created user: $userId")
                    users + (userId -> newUser)
                    Behaviors.same
                case LeftRoomNotification(user, roomName) =>
                    context.log.info(s"User $user received LeftRoomNotification for room: $roomName")
                    Behaviors.same
                case JoinRoomNotification(user, roomName) =>
                    context.log.info(s"User $user received JoinRoomNotification for room: $roomName")
                    Behaviors.same
                case _ =>
                    context.log.warn("Unknown message for UserActor")
                    Behaviors.same
            }
        }
}
```

**RoomActor**:

```
package Chat

import Chat.UserActor.{JoinRoomNotification, UserCommand}
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, Behavior}

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import scala.collection.mutable

object RoomActor {
    sealed trait RoomCommand

    case class CreateRoom(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], roomName: String) extends RoomCommand
    case class LeaveRoom(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], roomName: String) extends RoomCommand
    case class JoinRoom(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], roomName: String) extends RoomCommand
    case class BroadcastMessage(user: ActorRef[UserCommand], content: String) extends RoomCommand
    case class Room(roomName: String, owner: ActorRef[UserCommand], creationDate: LocalDateTime, users: mutable.Set[ActorRef[UserCommand]])

    def apply(): Behavior[RoomCommand] = roomBehavior(Map.empty)

    private def roomBehavior(rooms: Map[String, Room]): Behavior[RoomCommand] =
        Behaviors.receive { (context, message) =>
            message match {
                case CreateRoom(user, roomName) =>
                    val room = Room(roomName, user, LocalDateTime.now(), mutable.Set(user))
                    context.log.info(s"$user created room: $roomName")
                    roomBehavior(rooms + (roomName -> room))
                case LeaveRoom(user, roomName) =>
                    rooms.get(roomName).foreach { room =>
                        room.users -= user
                        if(user == room.owner) {
                            if(room.users.isEmpty) {
                                context.log.info(s"$user was the owner and the last user in room: $roomName. Removing the room.")
                                roomBehavior(rooms - roomName)
                            } else {
                                val newOwner = room.users.head
                                context.log.info(s"$user was the owner. Assigning the new owner: $newOwner")
                                val updatedRoom = room.copy(owner = newOwner)
                                roomBehavior(rooms + (roomName -> updatedRoom))
                            }
                        } else {
                            context.log.info(s"$user left the room: $roomName")
                            for (elem <- room.users) {
                                elem.tell(UserActor.LeftRoomNotification(user, roomName))
                            }
                            Behaviors.same
                        }
                    }
                    context.log.info(s"$user left room: $roomName")
                    Behaviors.same
                case JoinRoom(user, roomName) =>
                    rooms.get(roomName).foreach {room =>
                        room.users += user
                        user ! JoinRoomNotification(user, roomName)
                    }
                    Behaviors.same

                case BroadcastMessage(sender, content) =>
                    rooms.values.foreach{room =>
                        room.users.foreach{user =>
                            if(user != sender) {
                                user ! UserActor.ReceiveMessage(sender, content)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    context.log.info(s"Broadcast message from $sender: $content")
                    Behaviors.same

                case _ =>
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message for RoomActor")
                    Behaviors.same
            }
        }
}
```

**The output is:**

```
15:24:35: Executing ':Main.main()'...

> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :compileScala
    [Warn] : -target is deprecated: Use -release instead to compile against the correct platform API.
    one warning found

> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :Main.main()

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
15:24:49: Execution finished ':Main.main()'.
```

I've added Thread.sleep(5000), but the program still doesn't have any log output. I tried to add logback.xml with root level = "DEBUG" and "info". Also, I tried replace Thread.sleep by Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)

Comment: You may need to add the logback config, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html#logback

Comment: still get empty output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't running anything.

`Behaviors.xx` only creates a factory of actors, you have to explicitly let `ActorSystem` Spawn it. This is an example:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  sealed trait MainActor

  // setup your guardian actor here
  val guardianActor: Behavior[Any] = Behaviors.receive { (context, message) =>
    // like java constructor here
    val userActor = context.spawn(UserActor(), "userActor")
    // other...

    // react to message
    message match {
      case _ =>
        context.log.info("Unknown message for MainActor")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }

  // start ActorSystem here...
  val system: ActorSystem[Nothing] = ActorSystem(guardianActor, "ChatSystem")

}
```

One more thing, `system.systemActorOf` isn't recommended for the user, you need to create from guardian actor, which means the root (user) actor of ActorSystem.

If you want to create actor from anywhere, use the [SpawnProtocol](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#spawnprotocol)

Actually, the actor system itself is a root actor of JVM.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `extends App` mechanism is generally not a great idea for applications that will be concurrent, unless you're very careful.